# Thumbnail preview of secondary display on primary display?

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, multi-monitor, screenshot

Is there a way to display a miniature version of the secondary display's contents on the primary display? This is for doing a live demo during a presentation, while keeping a dual-display setup to also show notes on the primary display. I have a vague feeling that this should be possible *somehow*, but I don't have enough experience with xrandr.

A coarse internet search hasn't revealed anything useful. I'm aware of solutions like LibreOffice's presenter mode, or `pdf-presenter-console`. This question is about displaying interactive contents on the secondary console. A solution doesn't need to involve xrandr, a utility that captures a portion of the screen and clones it in another window would also work.

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually you can use vlc for that purpose (if I understand your needs correctly).

First you click on `Media -> Open Capture Device`
Then set `Capture mode` to `Desktop`.
Then you check show more options and at the end you can add a few options as sen [there](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help). But I guess you can figure it out yourself by trying. It depends on your screen resolution and which screen you want to record and display on which.

Comes from there : [How to record the desktop in VLC media player - second screen | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/782959/how-to-record-the-desktop-in-vlc-media-player-second-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Get a webcam and point it at the secondary screen, and privately live-stream the feed somewhere. Have the stream in a tiny window on your primary screen. It may not work well, but it will almost certainly work.